# Program compiles on one machine but not the other

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I would like to point out that I am still learning and it could be something obvious that I am missing.

But to the point:

For my assignment, we had to make a simple game that would display an interactive scene.

So I wrote all the code on my computer and everything works fine, the code compiles and the program runs exactly as intended.

I've decided to move it to my laptop because it is due tomorrow and now I got a problem.

When I try to compile exactly the same code, visual studio shows me an error at line:

```
_programID = glCreateProgram();
```

Which works perfectly fine on my desktop.

It says "Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in Project.exe: 0x00000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000."

The code is literally the same on both machines.

Both machines use windows 10 and exactly the same version of visual studio.

I have also linked my libraries relative to the solution directory so it is not a problem with a wrong path.

What could be the case? I really don't understand why is this happening. I have copied the entire folder with all the libraries and additional header files that I use along with the project.

I thought maybe it is because I am using libraries compiled on my desktop? Does that matter?

Please help.

Comment: try to update your graphic card driver on the machine with problem.

Comment: This means that the extensions/the opengl version is not loaded correctly. Thus the functionpointer glCreateProgram is a nullptr. How do you initialize the context? Which graphiccard is used in the notebook?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I don't think I've installed graphics card drivers on this laptop since last format so I'll do that now and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I write this in case somebody had a similar problem in the future:

The problem was with my graphics card driver on the laptop. After my last format I didn't install the drivers (didn't really think about it since I use my laptop only for office and simple visual studio stuff) and that was causing OpenGL functions to throw errors. Installing drivers fixed the problem.

Thank you very much @Humam Helfawi.